# RoleEnvironment initialization in Azure on IIS x64 bit throws an error

Tags: azure

I created webservice  that runs under IIS,  and it is x64 bit. I deployed it with custom install script on Azure machine (ws2008 r2). I created custom app pool (64 bit, Managed pipeline mode: Classic, .net v2, with NetworkService account as service user). Everything seems to be configured correctly but when I try to run my application I get following error:

System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for '' threw an exception. ---> .ModuleLoadException: The C++ module failed to load while attempting to initialize the default appdomain.

I can run standalone win form application and this method works correctly. What is more when I switch app pool to 32 bit and I run my application then it fail (because it has x64 bit components), however later when switch back to x64 it works correctly, RoleEnvironment returns correct data.

Do you have any ideas what can I do wrong when it comes to configuration, so this module cannot be loaded in x64 bit version?

Answer (score 0):

This may help. You can add a start-up task to your Windows Azure project's .csdef file to configure IIS to allow 32-bit modules in 64-bit applications.

In your Windows Azure project .csdef file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceDefinition>
  <WebRole ...>
... 
    <Startup>
      <Task commandLine="ConfigureIIS.cmd" executionContext="elevated" taskType="simple" />
    </Startup>
  </WebRole>
</ServiceDefinition>
```

ConfigureIIS.cmd (all one line):

%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set config -section:applicationPools -applicationPoolDefaults.enable32BitAppOnWin64:true

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would need to install VC++ x64 runtime in your Azure VM via startup task as some of the references you are using need VC++ run time.